# i'm having problems with my linked list i can display the contents of the list, but i cant find a node or find the length of the list

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public class IntNode {

    int data;
    IntNode link;

    IntNode() {

        this.link = null;

    }

    public IntNode(int initialData, IntNode initialLink) {

        data = initialData;
        link = initialLink;
    }

    public void addNode(int element) {
        link = new IntNode(element, link);
    }

    public int getData() {

        return data;
    }

    public IntNode getLink() {

        return link;
    }

    public void removeNodeAfter()

    {

        link = link.link;

    }

    public void setLink(IntNode newLink) {

        link = newLink;

    }

    void insertAtHead(int input) {
        input = data;
    }

    //this method doesnt work
    public int listLength(IntNode head) {
        IntNode cursor = 0;
        int ans;
        ans = 0;
        for (cursor = head; cursor != null; cursor = cursor.link)
        ans++;
        return ans;
    }

    //this method doesnt work either
    public boolean find(IntNode head, int searchKey) {

        if (head == null) {
            return false;
        }
        IntNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.data == searchKey) {
                return true;
            }
            current = current.link;
        }

        return false;

    }

import java.util.Scanner;

public class linkedList1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IntNode head;
        IntNode tail;

        head = new IntNode(10, null);
        head = new IntNode(20, head);
        head = new IntNode(25, head);
        head = new IntNode(30, head);

        while (head != null) {
            System.out.println(head.data);
            head = head.link;
        }

        IntNode node = new IntNode();

        System.out.println(node.listLength(null));

        if (node.find(head, 20)) System.out.println("found");

        else

          System.out.println("not found");

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: i understand thanks @Joe

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your linked list code. The problem is in your main method.  I have corrected it. I leave it as an exercise to you to figure out what you did wrong.

```
public class IntNode {

    int data;
    IntNode link;

    IntNode(){
        this.link = null ;
    }

    public IntNode(int initialData, IntNode initialLink)
    {
        data = initialData;
        link = initialLink ;
    }

    public void addNode(int element){
        link = new IntNode(element,link);
    }

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public IntNode getLink(){
        return link;
    }

    public void removeNodeAfter()
    {
        link = link.link;
    }

    public void setLink(IntNode newLink){
        link = newLink;
    }

    void insertAtHead(int input){
        input = data;
    }
    //this method doesnt work
    public int listLength(IntNode head){
        IntNode cursor = null;
        int ans;
        ans = 0;
        for(cursor=head; cursor!= null; cursor=cursor.link)
            ans++;
        return ans;
    }

    //this method doesnt work either
    public boolean find(IntNode head, int searchKey)
    {
        if(head == null){
            return false ;
        }
        IntNode current = head ;
        while(current != null){
            if(current.data == searchKey){
                return true ;
            }
            current = current.link ;
        }
        return false ;
    }
}

public class linkedList1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            IntNode head ;
            IntNode tail ;

            head = new IntNode(10, null);
            head = new IntNode(20,head);
            head = new IntNode(25, head);
            head = new IntNode(30,head);

            IntNode cur = head;
            while(cur!= null){
                System.out.println(cur.data);
                cur= cur.link;
            }

            IntNode node = new IntNode();

            System.out.println(node.listLength(head));

            if(node.find(head, 20))
                System.out.println("found");

            else

                System.out.println("not found");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the linkNode length, I would suggest a recursive function along the following

```
public int listLength(IntNode head, int count){
    if(head.getLink() == null)
        return count;
    else
        return listLength(head.getLink(), count+1);
}
```

For function like this, a call listLength(head, 1) where head is a single node will return a length 1, whereas a call listLength(head, 1) on a linked list with two nodes will return 2, etc.

For finding a particular value in this linked list, I would again suggest a recursive function along the following

```
public boolean find(IntNode head, int searchKey){
    // Check if this is the correct node
    if(head.getData() == searchKey)
        return true;
    // Check if this is the last node
    else if(head.getLink() == null)
        return false;
    else
        return find(head.getLink(), searchKey);
}
```

Hope this helps! P.S. Please format your questions better

Comment: --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
30
25
20
10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at IntNode.listLength(IntNode.java:57)
 at linkedList1.main(linkedList1.java:24)

Process completed.

Comment: i tried using the code you gave me and i get this error @Sishaar Rao

Comment: You need to provide more context. What is the line which throws this error. Perhaps debug to try and find what's going on, chances are you're passing in null as you do in System.out.println(node.listLength(null));

Comment: i changed it to System.out.println(node.listLength(head, 30));

Comment: Then make sure your head is not null. Debug and see whether you are correctly constructing a linked list.

Comment: @Dimuthu89 There is nothing wrong with your original linked list code.  The problem is in your `main` method, which I have corrected and posted as an answer.

Comment: @DavidChoweller thanks for helping me out but i still dont see what i did wrong, can you please give me a hint ?

Comment: Just compare your original main method with mine. It will be a good exercise.

Comment: By the way, I didn't change any of your other code.

Comment: @DavidChoweller  So what i saw is that you made a cur node and pointed it to head, and ran it through a while loop where the stopping case is when the node becomes null and printed the data in the cur node am i right ?

Comment: Yes. Your problem is that you made the `head` node run to the end of the list and eventually the `head` node became null.  Then later you tried to use this same `head` node to get the length of the list, and of course you got 0, because the length of a null list is 0. And of course, you didn't find any item in the list pointed to by `head`, because `head` was null.

Comment: I used `cur` to do the same thing that you used `head` to do.  So at the of my traversal, `head` still pointed to the start of your list.  So when I called the length and find methods on head, they succeeded.  The key thing to remember from this is that you shouldn't lose track of your head node, or you will lose the whole list.

Comment: @DavidChoweller thanks for breaking it down for me i get the concept now